# NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode Many-to-Many relations

Tags: nhibernate

I've created 2 objects:

```
public class Set
{
    public Set()
    {
        _sorts = new List<Sort>();
    }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
    private ICollection<Sort> _sorts;
    public virtual ICollection<Sort> Sorts
    {
        get { return _sorts; }
        set { _sorts = value; }
    }
}

public class Sort
{
    public Sort()
    {
        _sets = new List<Set>();
    }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    private ICollection<Set> _sets;
    public virtual ICollection<Set> Sets
    {
        get { return _sets; }
        set { _sets = value; }
    }
}
```

And 2 mappings:

```
public class SetMapping: ClassMapping<Set>
    {
        public SetMapping()
        {
            Table("Sets");
            Id(x => x.Id, map => map.Generator(IdGeneratorSelector.CreateGenerator()));
            Property(x => x.Code, map =>
            {
                map.Length(50);
                map.NotNullable(false);
            });
            Bag(x => x.Sorts, map =>
            {
                map.Key(k =>
                {
                    k.Column("SetId");
                    k.NotNullable(true);
                });
                map.Cascade(Cascade.All);
                map.Table("SetsToSorts");
                map.Inverse(true);

            }, r => r.ManyToMany(m => m.Column("SortId")));
        }
    }

    public class SortMapping: ClassMapping<Sort>
    {
        public SortMapping()
        {
            Table("Sorts");
            Id(x => x.Id, map => map.Generator(IdGeneratorSelector.CreateGenerator()));
            Property(x => x.Name, map =>
            {
                map.Length(50);
                map.NotNullable(false);
            });
        }
    }
```

usage:
Set can have many sorts
Sort can belong to many sets.

And I would like to use this as:

```
var set = new Set() {Code = "001"};
            var sort = new Sort {Name = "My name"};

            set.Sorts.Add(sort);
            sort.Sets.Add(set);
```

Somehow the relations are not working yet because when I try to use the above code to add sorts to set for example and commit then I don't see any records saved to the SetsToSorts linked table.

Does anyone have a clue what I'm missing in my mapping? Or otherwise doing wrong?

Thank you,
Joost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping says that Set's Sort collection is inverse (map.Inverse(true)). That means the other side of the bidirectional association is responsible for persisting changes.
But your Sort class mapping doesn't have any collection mapping. Remove map.Inverse(true) on SetMapping or add noninverse collection mapping to SortMapping.

Comment: Hi Hival, Thank you very much!
Live is so simple once you understand what something is doing. I was so close :)